# What is the forgetful functor for this simple finite category (based on the cyclic group C3)?

Tags: finite-groups, derived-functors

I am trying to understand what a forgetful functor is.

I have read the definition [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/forgetful+functor) but I still cannot figure out what the forgetful functor is exactly for the simple [cyclic group](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group) C3 viewed as a finite category.

EDIT:

More precisely, let's consider the category with only on object: the cyclic group C3, and all the group homomorphisms from C3 to C3 as arrows, in this case, what is the forgetful functor?

Could someone please enlighten me ?

Answer (score 1):

The forgetful functor from the category of groups to the category of sets simply forgets the  group structure. Formally if your group is $C_3 = (\{0,1,2\},+)$ where the group operation $+$ is addition mod 3, then applying the forgetful functor to $C_3$ yields the set $\{0,1,2\}.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do I understand correctly that a forgetful functor is derived from a homomorphism? If yes, what is the homomorphism in this case? Is a permutation of the group elements a homomorphism? For example the function : 1->2, 2->3, 3->1 ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What do you mean by "derived from a homomorphism"?

Comment: I think I am confused myself, I have just edited the question because the original question perhaps does not make much sense at all, does the edited question make more sense?

Comment: So, you're viewing $C_3$ as a groupoid. What do you mean by "forgetful functor", then? Forgetful functors don't act on categories, they act on algebraic objects such as groups, rings, vector spaces, and so on.

Comment: I was thinking that a functor brings one category to another. So in this case the forgetful functor would be , according to my vague understandig, a functor that brings C3 to its underlying set {1,2,3}, and brings the arrows (homomorphisms from C3 to C3) to plain old functions that project elements from the set {1,2,3} to the same set {1,2,3}. So in this case applying the forgetful functor to the simple finite category (with a single object C3) given in the question would bring that category to another finite category where the object is the underlying set {1,2,3} and the arrows are functions.

Comment: A functor maps *objects* of a category to objects of another category. The forgetful functor from the category of groups to the category of sets takes an *object* in the category of groups (a group) and maps it an object in the category of sets (its underlying set). It also maps group homomorphisms to their underlying set functions.

Comment: Does the functor not map also the arrows of a category? Also, for simplicity I was trying to consider a finite category, namely the one which has only one object : the group C3 and homomorpisms from C3 to C3 as arrows.

Comment: Yes, it also maps arrows, which is why I said "It also maps group homomorphisms to their underlying set functions." What I'm trying to tell you that there is no meaningful notion of "forgetful functor" from the category $C_3$ to another category. There *is* a meaningful notion of forgetful functor from the category of groups to the category of sets.

Comment: I try to think about this more deeply. Thanks for the comments.